# RXJava apply function to each element in Observable and return it´s observable

Tags: android, retrofit, reactive-programming, rx-java

I have a retrofit service that returns an Observable and save it everytime it´s loaded.

My Retrofit service:

```
@GET("url")
Observable<Order> getOrder();
```

And the function:

```
return SERVICE.getOrder()
            .map(order -> {
                save(order);
                return order;
            });
```

But if you see I just do save and return the same object, is there any simpler way?

Comment: are you looking for `doOnEach` https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Observable-Utility-Operators#dooneach ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking `doOnNext`

```
return SERVICE.getOrder()
            .doOnNext(order -> {
                    save(order);
            })
```

It's invokes action, that simply accepts the emitted item.
Note, that `doOnNext` calls on observer's thread

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its better to use:

```
        .subscribe(new Action1<StatsChartData>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Order order) {
                save(order);
            }
        });
```

Map is used to apply some changes to each item.

Comment: but I return the Observer, I want to apply it "secretly" to the subscriber

Comment: what do you mean with "secretly"?

Comment: Not sure if there exists another way?

Comment: I have that return inside an "api" and I want to save it every time anyone calls it.